# How do use pressesBegan function?

Tags: swift, uikit

Actually I want to detect key presses from iPhone(physical device)'s keyboard. Therefore, i'm trying to use the `pressesBegan` function in my project. This function is working on iOS simulator when I press my macbook's keyboard's keys, but, whenever I test my app in my real/physical device that is iPhone 14 Pro Max, the function is not working at all. How do I solve this problem?

I have tried this code:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let nameTextField = UITextField()
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        nameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2
        nameTextField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        nameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameTextField.textColor = .black
        nameTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return nameTextField
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(nameTextField)
        
        nameTextField.delegate = self
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            nameTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            nameTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }


    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        print("pressesBegan")
        guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Edit your question with more specific details. Also include information about what class you put this in. Are you sure you want `pressesBegan` and not `touchesBegan`?

Comment: `pressesBegan` is for handling physical key presses from an external keyboard. It's not used for handling key presses as the user types with the on-screen keyboard of an iOS device. If you want to handle text being entered into the text field then implement the appropriate UITextFieldDelegate methods.